# QWebView always fails to load website

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I am running QtCreator 3.2.0, based on Qt 5.3.1 on Windows 8.1.

It seems that no matter what website i am trying to load, the onLoadFinished slot always returns *false*. I tried to load websites with and without SSL, both failed.

When I tried to load local resources everything worked well. So i monitored my network with wireshark and my Qt application does not even send a request, i also checked the QUrl with QUrl::isValid(), tried to use QWebView::load() instead of QWebView::setUrl() and ran my application as Administrator. Nothing worked.

I can't find any errors in my code and i somewhat feel like this is a bug, but I'm not certain about that.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->webView->page()->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(errorcheck(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url("http://www.nasa.gov/");
    ui->webView->setUrl(url);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_webView_loadFinished(bool arg1)
{
    ui->label->setText(arg1 ? "success" : "failure");
}

void MainWindow::errorcheck(QNetworkReply* QNR) {
    qDebug() << QNR->errorString();
}
```

The output is: `"Host www.nasa.gov not found"`

Comment: @Chernobyl yes i did add "QT += webkitwidgets", the application compiles and starts

Comment: In "Windows 8" I had the same problem, was the question of parental control.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
connect(QWebView->page()->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
this, SLOT(errorcheck(QNetworkReply*)));

void MainWindow::errorcheck(QNetworkReply* QNR) {
qDebug()<<QNR->errorString;
}
```

And check if any error occure.

Comment: For the given example it outputs `"Host www.nasa.gov not found"`.

Comment: Try this one to determine if it is QWebView or all QT libs. `QTcpSocket S; S.connectToHost("http://nasa.gov",80);if (S.waitForConnected()) { qDebug()<<"Socket connected" } else { qDebug()<<"Socket cannot connect to nasa.gov"`

Comment: It returns `Socket cannot connect to nasa.gov` so I guess its an issue with all Qt libraries, or my setup ...

Comment: I guess you can ping the www.nasa.gov (Maybe blocked ip,just guess)? Do you have "QT += network" line?

Comment: Also post what firewall/antivirus do you have, eg. COMODO can block all network requests while application is in a sandbox.

Comment: I just solved my Problem. It was Kaspersky Internet Security denying the connection. Your help was appreciated non the less!